# PHP - reformat multidimensional array to insert into MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can I parse php array like this:

```
$cars= array(
    "Ford"=>array("C-Max"=>array("length"=>"4333","width"=>"1825","height"=>"1560"),"Escape"=>array("length"=>"4480","width"=>"1845","height"=>"1730")
    ,"Explorer"=>array("length"=>"4912","width"=>"1872","height"=>"1849"),"Fiesta"=>array("length"=>"3950","width"=>"1973","height"=>"1433")
    ,"Focus"=>array("length"=>"4488","width"=>"1840","height"=>"1497"),"Fusion"=>array("length"=>"4013","width"=>"1724","height"=>"1543")
    ,"Galaxy"=>array("length"=>"4820","width"=>"1854","height"=>"1723"),"Kuga"=>array("length"=>"4443","width"=>"1842","height"=>"1677")
    ,"Mondeo"=>array("length"=>"4844","width"=>"1886","height"=>"1500"),"Ranger"=>array("length"=>"5075","width"=>"1805","height"=>"1745")
    ,"S-Max"=>array("length"=>"4768","width"=>"1854","height"=>"1658"),
    "Hummer"=>array("H2"=>array("length"=>"5170","width"=>"2063","height"=>"2012"),"H3"=>array("length"=>"4782","width"=>"1989","height"=>"1872")));
```

to insert into MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars_dimensions` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `brand` varchar(120) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(120) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `length` varchar(5) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `width` varchar(5) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `height` varchar(5) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When I use `foreach` and like `$cars["Hummer"]["H2"]["length"];` I somehow can't get another array dimension and cache the actual brand/model at the same time... Tho, my actual array is about 3000 items in the first dimension (brands).

Comment: Every answer so far assumes that Hummer is on the same level as Ford, but in your example it isn't, perhaps that's just a typo though. If it is their code will work, if it isn't none of the 3 answers so far are appropriate.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just copy-pasted the code in a wrong way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two loops, one for the brands and one for their models:

```
foreach ($cars as $brand => $models) {
    foreach ($models as $model => $specs) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO cars_demensions (brand, model, length, weight, height)
                  VALUES ('$brand', '$model', {$specs['length']}, {$specs['width']}, {$specs['height']});";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $cars as $brandname => $carinfo  )
{
foreach ( $carinfo  as $modelname => $car )
{
// brand = $brandname
// model = $modelname
// length = $car['length']
// do insert query here
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = '';
foreach($cars AS $brand) {
  foreach($brand AS $model) {
    if(!empty($rows)) $rows .= ', ';
    $rows = "({$car['width']},...)";
  }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO cars_dimensions (width,...) VALUES $rows";
```

Answer (score 0):

Full executable code and **TESTED**. This is more efficient and faster way to do this. Using this way you can insert multiple row using a single insert query.

```
<?php 
$col = [];
foreach ($cars as $brand => $models) {
    foreach ($models as $model => $specs) {
        if (isset($specs['length']) || isset($specs['width']) || isset($specs['height'])) {
            $length = $specs['length'];
            $width = $specs['width'];
            $height = $specs['height'];
        } else {
            foreach ($specs as $k => $v) {
                $length = $v['length'];
                $width = $v['width'];
                $height = $v['height'];
            }
        }
        $col[] = "('" . $brand . "', '" . $model . "', '" . $length . "', '" . $width . "', '" . $height . "')";
    }
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `cars_dimensions`(`brand`, `model`, `length`, `width`, `height`) VALUES" . implode(',', $col) . ";";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec($query);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Hopefully it should help you. Thank you.