# how to Insert multi dimensional array in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - reformat multidimensional array to insert into MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362116/php-reformat-multidimensional-array-to-insert-into-mysql)

what I want to  do is insert multi dimensional array in my database

here is my code,but it not working,

```
include 'config/config.php';
    $Currentdatetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s" ,strtotime("now"));
    $senderID = '530738657,100003201126721,659276806,etc';
    $explode = implode(', ', array_shift($senderID));
    $result = array();
    foreach ($senderID as $row) {
        $result[] = "(" . implode(', ', $row) . ")";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_invite ($explode) VALUES('$userid','implode (', ', $result)','0','50','$Currentdatetime','0')");
```

any solution? thanks

Comment: Your $expolade should have database table coloumn names.

Comment: `array_shift` on a string? Bold move! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_shift on senderID is an error senderID is a string!!!!

foreach on senderID is an error !!!!!

replace this

```
 $senderID = '530738657,100003201126721,659276806,etc';
```

with

```
     $senderID = explode(',', $senderID   );
    $senderID = '530738657,100003201126721,659276806,etc';
```

Comment: thanks, I type wrong in my code and i solved it already,